# .NET Framework NULL Stack Trace in Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've been working on a service application which takes in real-time data using a 3rd party library.  The library is threaded and notifies my application through raised events.  At some varying point in time a NullReferenceException is thrown, however any information that is helpful in locating where the exception occurred is not provided within the exception object.

Could the reason why there isn't a stack trace or any other useful information be because the 3rd party library is threaded, compiled for release, or both?

**EDIT:** The 3rd party library is a managed wrapper around unmanaged C++

Here is a JSON representation of the exception object:

```
{
    "ExceptionObject": {
        "ClassName": "System.NullReferenceException",
        "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2147467261,
        "Source": null,
        "WatsonBuckets": null
    },
    "IsTerminating": true
}
```

Comment: A NRE can also originate in unmanaged code.  Exact same failure mode, using a pointer that has an address less than 0x000010000.  Usually 0.  But no stack trace, only managed code allows reliable stackwalks.  You need a debugger.  Or a telephone number and a good short repro project so the 3rd party can repro the problem.

Comment: Got it.  The 3rd party library is a managed wrapper around unmanaged code so that makes a lot of sense.  I've been methodically wrapping everything and rerunning my application in order to ensure that it wasn't my code causing the issue.  I will get in contact with the vendor.